# Was there any scientic research backing up the setting of the reference range of cholesterol up to 200 mg/dl?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, cholesterol

I am now holding the original, Polish edition of a book called "The Hidden Therapies - What your doctor won't tell you" authored by Jerzy Zięba, who is widely considered to be a quack by medical authorities in my country. Nevertheless, the sheer amount of facts (or "facts"?) and research papers cited by Mr. Zięba warrants some closer skeptical attention.

Among many other claims Mr. Zięba says that the reference range of cholesterol in human blood of up to 200 mg/dl are backed up by no prior scientific research on the subject; and even after setting this reference range there has still been no such research.

By appropriate scientific studies to back this up Mr. Zięba seems to primarily mean testing cholesterol levels among numerous (thousands) healthy people, taking the average, removing most extreme values and treating the obtained range as the reference range.

Was there any scientific research that would back up the reference range of cholesterol concentration in human blood of up to 200 mg/dl?

Comment: Is there a supporting paper cited?

Comment: @npst Not for this claim in this chapter. Haven't yet thoroughly read the whole book, though.